# c# regex high cpu usage

Tags: c#, regex

my little program is checking what type of script website use and it use over 80% cpu i7 processor. I wonder is it normal?

Code:

```
public static class EnginesMatcher
{

    public static readonly Regex Drupal1 =
        new Regex(
            @"/misc/drupal\.js|Drupal\.settings|href=""http://drupal\.org""|\?q=node/[0-9]+|/\?q=user/register|/\?q=user/password|/user/register\?destination|<li class=""collapsed""><a href=""/node/add"">|/dpl3/files/|/modules/node/",
            RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static readonly Regex XE1 =
        new Regex(
        @"XpressEngine|content=""zeroboardXE|content=""xe_board""|var zbxe_session_name|/xe\.css\?2|/xeicon/favicon\.ico""|#xe-editor-container-1|xpress_xeditor",
            RegexOptions.Compiled);

    //and 60 more such regex
```

In another class

```
  public async Task<Result> Match(string url)
        {

            if (!await Open(url).ConfigureAwait(false)) return ResultKey;


            if (EnginesMatcher.Drupal1.IsMatch(html))
            {
                return new Result()
                {
                    Key = AResultKey.Success,
                    LogFile = "Drupal.txt",
                    Message = "Drupal",
                    Url = url
                };
            }
            if (EnginesMatcher.XE1.IsMatch(html))
            {
                return new Result()
                {
                    Key = AResultKey.Success,
                    LogFile = "Drupal.txt",
                    Message = "Drupal",
                    Url = url
                };
            }
```

The Match(url) function is in ForeachAsyncLoop, the program check about 4000 links/minute. When I disable all regexs it uses up to 20% cpu, can I increase regex performance?*emphasized text*

Comment: I am interested in seeing the answers for this as i have noticed this too

Comment: Regex uses a lot of cpu because of it's features. If you know exactly what you are looking for it can be a lot faster to do the matching yourself without regex. Also doing pruning can make it faster (aka. removing stuff you know you don't need to check)

Comment: Are you really surprised this type of code uses a ton of CPU?

Comment: Maybe not surpised but I wonder it can be faster

Comment: The regexes you have there essentially all test for verbatim strings (with very few exceptions). The .NET engine should be handling those pretty fast, probably as fast as (if not faster than) any string matching routines you may write on your own. So my guess is that you have another regex further down the line (one of the "other 60" regexes) that exhibits pathological behavior (like [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)). You need to profile the regexes separately and find out where exactly your CPU load is generated.

Comment: CPU usage is high with this two regex - no matter if I have this 2 or another 60 - usage is the same but speed is bigger - about 10000links/minute I don't have any .* regexs

Comment: What kind of app is this? Console? Does it do anything else but regex? Any computational program (that is a program that does not have waits of any kind) is supposed to use CPU. From your description it's not clear what is that that makes you think this might not be normal.

Comment: @ekapek - See my answer, try combining the regexs into a single regex (shameless self promotion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably can't speed it up very with regular expressions. However, you can probably do a lot better by using a different algorithm.

The [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) is designed to do exactly what you're doing: looking for a fixed set of strings in a large body of text.

The standard algorithm doesn't support regular expressions, but your regexes are verbatim strings. That is, you're looking for `this|that|something else|something more`. Which is the same as looking for four different strings.

I published an implementation of the [Aho-Corasick algorithm in C#](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=869) a few years ago. With a few modifications to the way you do things, it should work well.

Start by building a dictionary of the strings you're looking for and the corresponding web sites:

```
Dictionary<string, string> StringsToSites = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Then, add the strings. For example, for Drupal you'd add:

```
StringsToSites.Add("/misc/drupal\.js", "Drupal");
StringsToSites.Add("Drupal.settings", "Drupal");
StringsToSites.Add(@"href=""http://drupal\.org"", "Drupal");
// problem with this one ...   |\?q=node/[0-9]+
StringsToSites.Add("?q=user/register", "Drupal");
// etc., etc.
```

Note that there's a problem with things that are not verbatim strings. There's no way for the implementation to match "?q=node/[0-9]+/". The best we could do is add the string "?q=node/".

Then, create a matcher and populate it:

```
AhoCorasickStringSearcher matcher = new AhoCorasickStringSearcher();
foreach (var key in StringsToSites.Keys)
{
    matcher.AddItem(key);
}
matcher.CreateFailureFunction();
```

Then, for every link you see, call `matcher.Search`:

```
var Matches = matcher.Search(link);
```

That will give you a collection of `StringMatch` objects. You can look up the `Text` in the dictionary to see which site it matches. For example:

```
foreach (var m in Matches)
{
    string site;
    if (StringsToSites.TryGetValue(m.Text, out site))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text '{0}' matches site '{1}'.", m.Text, site);
    }
}
```

I would expect this to be at least 10 times as fast as your regex solution, possibly 100 times as fast.

Answer (score 1):

The heirchy of what you are doing is this:

1. The engine will try to match the alternations in order from the beginning of the string.
2. In the order that you call your regexes.

In trying to accomplish 1 & 2, you could combine all your regexes into a single regex.
I don't think this would incur a performance penalty in combining them. Might even be more effecient.

Its worth exploring since this is probably going to be a slow point in your code anyway.

So, the equivalent to what you are doing is this:

```
  Regex rxAll = new Regex(
      @"
           (?:
                ^ [\S\s]*
                (?<Drupal1>
                     /misc/drupal\.js
                  |  Drupal\.settings
                  |  href=""http://drupal\.org""
                  |  \?q=node/ [0-9]+
                  |  /\?q=user/register
                  |  /\?q=user/password
                  |  /user/register\?destination
                  |  <li\ class=""collapsed""><a\ href=""/node/add"">
                  |  /dpl3/files/
                  |  /modules/node/
                )
             |
                ^ [\S\s]*
                (?<XE1>
                     XpressEngine
                  |  content=""zeroboardXE
                  |  content=""xe_board""
                  |  var\ zbxe_session_name
                  |  /xe\.css\?2
                  |  /xeicon/favicon\.ico""
                  |  \#xe-editor-container-1
                  |  xpress_xeditor
                )
           )
      ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

  string html =
      @"
         <a class=""x-fn"" href=""javascript:void(0);"">
         <a class='x-fn' href = ""javascript:void(0); "">
         <a href='javascript:void(0);' class=x-fn >
         <a class=""x-fn"" href=javascript:void(0); >
         <a 'hello' href=javascript:void(0); world class=x-fn content=""xe_board"">
      ";

  Match matches = rxAll.Match( html );
  if (matches.Success)
  {
      if (matches.Groups["Drupal1"].Success)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Matched Drupal1 -> {0}", matches.Groups["Drupal1"].Value);
          return;
      }
      if (matches.Groups["XE1"].Success)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Matched XE1 -> {0}", matches.Groups["XE1"].Value);
          return;
      }
  }
  return;
```

Edit:  BTW, I used RegexFormat (.com) program on your regexs. These Verbatim regex were
made with a couple of button clicks. So, you can use a tool to do all the work for you.